# APC Back-UPS overload

Tags: battery, power, ups

I contacted APC to ask this question, but it has been 5 days with no response.

My question is simple: I have an APC Back-UPS ES 750 (450 watts), but let's say I want to plug something that draws more power (let's say 650 watts).

On the UPS, there are 2 sides: "Surge protection" and "Battery Backup+ / Surge protection".

I know the battey won't hold if power goes out.

But can I plug the thing that draws 650 watts into the "Surge protection" side without experiencing any problem at all?

Thanks in advance.

Model: http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BE750G

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you can. The device has a *Total Amperage* of 12 amperes which is 1440 watts, where as the 5 UPS outlets only have an output of 450 watts, the other 5 surge only outlets aren't limited by that but instead are limited by the 12 ampere fuse on the device.

This is stated in [the specifications in the user guide for the device on APC's page](http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BE750G&tab=documentation).

Internally the device is a 12 ampere surge protector with 5 outlets and a sixth internal one that feeds a 450 watt or about 3 ampere UPS that then in turn has 5 outlets of its own.

Answer (score 3):

Infact "YES". the maximum output for the above said UPS is 450W and for your question is well answered in the [technical document](http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BE750G&tab=features) of APC Back-UPS ES 750.Maximum output for the two outlet is 450W and one will protect your sensitive devices like hardisk and the other protect only secondary electronics components from surge.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just want to make sure I understand. If I plug something that draws more power, I won't have surge protection and it would be like plugging it directly into the wall?

Comment: yes you are right. But you have to worry about the output watts.it will be the maximum capacity for the whole circuitry and connecting something that draws more than the said will lead to a damage to the UPS.It will be like connecting a LED directly to a 12V

Comment: 450 watts is the output limit on the UPS outlets but the surge only outlets are only limited by the 12 ampere fuse on the device. And as such this answer is incorrect. Connecting something that draws more current than allowed will only result in the reset-able fuse breaking the circuit.

Comment: @DanD : I also stated the same but from a different angle.

Comment: But the answer to whether the OP can plug a 650 watt load into the surge outlets of the device is actually, yes, not no as your answer states.